# automatic iframe resizing with bootstrap grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How do I grow an iframe to match it's height when using bootstrap grids? from what I know, iframes have a fixed height, but when I use a grid to adjust the columns it doesn't resize. So using other solutions that set the height on load does not work.

```
<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div>
                <DIV>
                    <DIV>
                        <IFRAME XXXstyle="min-height: 100%; width:100%" xstyle="BORDER-TOP: 0px; HEIGHT: 100%; BORDER-RIGHT: 0px; WIDTH: 100%; BORDER-BOTTOM: 0px; BORDER-LEFT: 0px" 
                            frameBorder=0
                            scrolling=no src="footer.html">
                        </IFRAME>
                    </DIV>
                </DIV>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For footer.html I have:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 ">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 ">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 ">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 ">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working like this, plus calling it in the body onload event.

I've no idea how to jqueryfy the body onload event with this though...

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
  resizeFrame(document.getElementById('footerIFRAME'))
});

function resizeFrame(f) {
  f.style.height = f.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px";
}
```